# How to get a webpage content with Eclipse (Android ADT)

Tags: java, android, eclipse, html

I'm developing an android application and I'm using Eclipse ADT.
I want to get the content of a webpage that say only true or false

Here is my code of my MainActivity.java

```
package com.appmobirep;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

    public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        addButtonClickListner();
    }

    public void addButtonClickListner() 
    {
        Button btnLogin = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnTest);
        btnLogin.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // Need to get the webpage content and set it to a string
                String Data = "";
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    }
```

Can you please help me on this
Thank you...

Comment: do you mean web services?

Comment: its almost like ajax in javascript. i want to call a webpage (data.php) and get the data from that webpage